# How to execute custom code on VSIX package uninstallation?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vsix, vspackage

Is there any way to clean registry entries or invoke any custom logic when VSIX package (your package you've coded, not just an arbitrary one) is being removed from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you would need a MSI-based installation for custom actions